# SignalR hub doesn't recreate connection after restart

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

I'm having JavaScript SignalR client and .NET SignalR server application. After application redeployment by Octopus Deploy the client stops receivng any messages from the server, although the server receives messages from the client and tries to send messages back.

More detailed behavior:

1. Client opens connection with id '5dd083cc-f7fe-4b7d-8cae-d0e87b35d51c'
2. Connection '5dd083cc-f7fe-4b7d-8cae-d0e87b35d51c' is created on the server.
3. Client sends messages to the server, server sends messages to the client. Everything is ok.
4. Server is redeployed by Octopus Deploy.
5. Client sends message to the server from the same connection. Message is received by the server.
6. Server sends message to the client. Message is not received.

After server restart in application logs I see that messages from the client are received by the server but I don't see that connection was created. 
Should I manually create SignalR connections after restart?
Can messages from the client be received without created connection?

Here is the module I use for logging:

```
public class LoggingPipelineModule : HubPipelineModule
{
    protected override void OnIncomingError(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, IHubIncomingInvokerContext invokerContext)
    {
        Logging.Logger.Error(exceptionContext.Error.Message, exceptionContext.Error);
        base.OnIncomingError(exceptionContext, invokerContext);
    }

    protected override bool OnBeforeIncoming(IHubIncomingInvokerContext context)
    {
        Logging.Logger.Debug(string.Format(
            "Invoking '{0}' on server hub '{1}' with connection id '{2}'",
            context.MethodDescriptor.Name, 
            context.MethodDescriptor.Hub.Name,
            context.Hub.Context.ConnectionId));

        return base.OnBeforeIncoming(context);
    }

    protected override bool OnBeforeOutgoing(IHubOutgoingInvokerContext context)
    {
        var connection = context.Connection as Connection;
        if (connection != null)
        {
            Logging.Logger.Debug(string.Format(
               "Invoking '{0}' on client hub '{1}' with connection id '{2}'",
               context.Invocation.Method,
               context.Invocation.Hub,
               connection.Identity));
        }
        else
        {
            Logging.Logger.Debug(string.Format(
              "Invoking '{0}' on client hub '{1}'",
              context.Invocation.Method,
              context.Invocation.Hub));
        }

        return base.OnBeforeOutgoing(context);
    }

    protected override void OnAfterConnect(IHub hub)
    {
        Logging.Logger.Debug(string.Format("New connection with id {0} is established", hub.Context.ConnectionId));
        base.OnAfterConnect(hub);
    }

    protected override void OnAfterDisconnect(IHub hub, bool stopCalled)
    {
        Logging.Logger.Debug(string.Format("Connection with id {0} was closed", hub.Context.ConnectionId));
        base.OnAfterDisconnect(hub, stopCalled);
    }

    protected override void OnAfterReconnect(IHub hub)
    {
        Logging.Logger.Debug(string.Format("Connection with id {0} was recreated", hub.Context.ConnectionId));
        base.OnAfterReconnect(hub);
    }
}
```

Here are the application logs (there is no connection creation):

```
2017-03-28 08:40:58,915 [62] DEBUG Invoking 'Push' on client hub 'ServerHub' with connection id '5dd083cc-f7fe-4b7d-8cae-d0e87b35d51c'
2017-03-28 08:41:18,213 [88] DEBUG Invoking 'Unsubscribe' on server hub 'ServerHub' with connection id '5dd083cc-f7fe-4b7d-8cae-d0e87b35d51c'
2017-03-28 08:41:18,447 [64] DEBUG Invoking 'Subscribe' on server hub 'ServerHub' with connection id '5dd083cc-f7fe-4b7d-8cae-d0e87b35d51c'
2017-03-28 08:41:23,916 [64] DEBUG Invoking 'Unsubscribe' on server hub 'ServerHub' with connection id '5dd083cc-f7fe-4b7d-8cae-d0e87b35d51c'
2017-03-28 08:41:24,151 [62] DEBUG Invoking 'Subscribe' on server hub 'ServerHub' with connection id '5dd083cc-f7fe-4b7d-8cae-d0e87b35d51c'
```